# Changing menu item visibility in a destination

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

Using androidx navigation framework, I am able to switch between navigation fragment destinations (both using menu and other in-fragment actions). Now, I need to show a share button when I am in a given destination, and hide it in all the others.

I managed to do this, but I need to invoke `invalidateOptionsMenu()` each time a destination is changed. Is this the right way or are there any more elegant ways?

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var isGivenDestination = false
    ...
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        navHostFragment.navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener {_, destination, _ ->
            invalidateOptionsMenu()
            isGivenDestination = destination.id == R.id.given_destination
        }
    }
    override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val result = super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
        menu?.findItem(R.id.nav_share)?.let {
            if (it.isVisible != isGivenDestination) {
                it.isVisible = isGivenDestination
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```